# Adding a file using FileStream is raising the following error "The given path's format is not supported"

Tags: development, csom

I have the following code to add a file inside a folder:-

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(context.Site.Url + templetefile.File.ServerRelativeUrl, FileMode.Open))
              {
                    FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
                    fci.Overwrite = false;
                    fci.Url = destUrl;
                    fci.ContentStream = fs;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File destFile = shareddocsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci);

                    context.Load(destFile);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                                }
```

but i am getting this exception `The given path's format is not supported` on the `FileStream fs = new FileStream(context.Site.Url + templetefile.File.ServerRelativeUrl, FileMode.Open)`.. although the `context.Site.Url + templetefile.File.ServerRelativeUrl` will generate a url as follow `https://*****.sharepoint.com/OrderManagement/OrderTemplates/Request for Approval.oft`.. which is a valid url to a file... so can anyone advice on this error please?

Comment: FileStream is used to read files from local/ network location. Are you trying to move/ copy file from one SharePoint location to another? If it is 2 different environments then you can use the solution posted here. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221839/copy-files-from-one-site-collection-to-another-csom

Comment: @UBK as per this documentation the FileStream can be used for SharePoint online https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint , and i am trying to move a file from one folder inside SharePoint to another folder ...

Comment: Hi, yes, FileStream can be used, but only when you are uploading it from your local or network folder. Please check CopyTo -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee542558(v=office.15) or MoveTo -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee542413(v%3Doffice.15) methods if you are trying to copy from one folder to another in same SharePoint site. In case of across sites, you can refer to the post I've mentioned in earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

From above comments, I see that you want to move files/folders to another folder. If so, you can have a try following easy way:

[MoveCopyUtil.MoveFolder method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/mt844929%28v%3Doffice.15%29)

Code:

```
        string SiteUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dest";     

        var pwd = "******";
        var username = "abc@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";

        var authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
        ClientContext context = authManager.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(SiteUrl, username, pwd);

        string sourceFolder = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/source/test doc lib/testfolder";
        string destFolder = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dest/Shared Documents/testfoldermove";

        MoveCopyUtil.MoveFolder(context, sourceFolder, destFolder,new MoveCopyOptions { 
            KeepBoth=false,
            RetainEditorAndModifiedOnMove=false
        });
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```